# How to get the selected text focus again after contenteditable lost focus and gained it back programmartically

Tags: javascript, forms, focus, contenteditable, dom-events

I have a div that the contenteditable attribute is true,

```
<div tabindex="1" id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I have another div that acts like a button

```
<div>Click Me</div>
```

The problem am having is that after typing inside the editor box, I selected some text and when I clicked on the "click me" div the editor box looses focus and thus removing the highlighted text.

I used in js to programmatically send the focus back

```
document.getElementById("editor").focus()
```

But after this the selected text is no more selected the cusor just moves to the beginning of the editor box.

How do I get the focus to make sure the initial selected text is selected again after the click me has been clicked

Answer (score 0):

One solution is setting [`user-select: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select#Browser_compatibility) on your button-like `div`. If the browsers you care about support it, it's the simplest (but as discussed in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511312/1026), someone reported problems with getting it to work in Safari...)

Otherwise you'll have to save and restore the selection using JS, the [text range module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) of rangy.js is useful for that. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546051/1026 for a usage example; in your case you'll need to save the selection onblur and restore it after processing the click on the button-like `div`.