# User-select: none behaves differently in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, rangy

### What I am trying to achieve

I am building input-like content editable div. You are supposed to click some tags outside the div to add them inside the div while also being able to type around said tags.

### The problem and how to reproduce it

I am using user-select: none (normal and webkit) to keep tag buttons from being selected, therefore losing my caret's position. It works in Firefox and Chrome but not in Safari (I aware of the -webkit- prefix and using it).

[Here is a fiddle where you can reproduce the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/Darkkz/r1u649pj/3/)

### What I've tried

The root of my problem was maintaining the caret's position while leaving the content editable div.

I have previously tried to use rangy but got stuck in some limitations regarding Firefox. These limitations where quite annoying from an UX standpoint. You can check my previous question and how it got me here, to this user-select: none solution  -[Caret disappears in Firefox when saving its position with Rangy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373053/caret-disappears-in-firefox-when-saving-its-position-with-rangy)

That's how I got to this solution featuring user-select: none.

My components/JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
        data(){
            return {
                filters_toggled: false,
                fake_input_content: '',
                input_length: 0,
                typed: false,
                boolean_buttons: [{
                    type: '1',
                    label: 'ȘI',
                    tag: 'ȘI',
                    img: 'https://i.imgur.com/feHin0S.png'
                }, {
                    type: '2',
                    label: 'SAU',
                    tag: 'SAU',
                    img: 'https://i.imgur.com/vWJeJwb.png'
                }, {
                    type: '3',
                    label: 'NU',
                    tag: 'NU',
                    img: 'https://i.imgur.com/NNg1spZ.png'
                }],
                saved_sel: 0,
                value: null,
                options: ['list', 'of', 'options']
            }
        },
        name: 'boolean-input',
        methods: {
            inputLength($event){
                this.input_length = $event.target.innerText.length;
                if(this.input_length == 0)
                    this.typed = false;
            },
            addPlaceholder(){
                if(this.input_length == 0 && this.typed == false){
                    this.$refs.divInput.innerHTML = 'Cuvinte cheie, cautare booleana..'
                }
            },
            clearPlaceholder(){
                if(this.input_length == 0 && this.typed == false){
                    this.$refs.divInput.innerHTML = '';
                }
            },
            updateBooleanInput($event){
                this.typed = true;
                this.inputLength($event);
            },
            saveCursorLocation($event){
        /*
                if($event.which != 8){
                    if(this.saved_sel)
                        rangy.removeMarkers(this.saved_sel)
                    this.saved_sel = rangy.saveSelection();
                }
                */
                // if(this.input_length == 0 && this.typed == false){
                //  var div = this.$refs.divInput;
                //  var sel = rangy.getSelection();
                //  sel.collapse(div, 0);
                // }
            },
            insertNode: function(node){
                var selection = rangy.getSelection();
                var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                range.insertNode(node);
                range.setStartAfter(node);
                range.setEndAfter(node);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
            },
            addBooleanTag($event){
                // return this.$refs.ChatInput.insertEmoji($event.img);
                if (!this.$refs.divInput.contains(document.activeElement)) {
                    this.$refs.divInput.focus();
                }

                console.log(this.input_length);
                if(this.typed == false & this.input_length == 0){
                    this.$refs.divInput.innerHTML = ''
                    var space = '';
                    this.typed = true
                    //this.saveCursorLocation($event);
                }
                //rangy.restoreSelection(this.saved_sel);
        console.log(getSelection().anchorNode, getSelection().anchorOffset, getSelection().focusNode, getSelection().focusOffset)

                var node = document.createElement('img');
                node.src = $event.img;
                node.className = "boolean-button--img boolean-button--no-margin";
                node.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                    // event.currentTarget.node.setAttribute('contenteditable','false');
                    this.$refs.divInput.removeChild(node);
                })
                this.insertNode(node);
                this.saveCursorLocation($event);
            },
            clearHtmlElem($event){
                var i = 0;
                var temp = $event.target.querySelectorAll("span, br");
                if(temp.length > 0){
                    for(i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
                        if(!temp[i].classList.contains('rangySelectionBoundary')){
                            if (temp[i].tagName == "br"){
                                temp[i].parentNode.removeChild(temp[i]);
                            } else {
                                temp[i].outerHTML = temp[i].innerHTML;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            pasted($event){
                $event.preventDefault();
                var text = $event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                this.insert(document.createTextNode(text));
                this.inputLength($event);
                this.typed == true;
            },
            insert(node){
                this.$refs.divInput.focus();
                this.insertNode(node);
                this.saveCursorLocation($event);
            },
            fixDelete(){

            }
        },
        props: [ 'first'],
        mounted() {
            this.addPlaceholder()
        }
})
```

My HTML

```
<div id="app">
        <div class="input__label-wrap">
            <span class="input__label">Cauta</span>
            <div style="user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none">
                <span readonly v-on:click="addBooleanTag(b_button)" v-for="b_button in boolean_buttons" class="boolean-buttons">{{b_button.label}}</span>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="input__boolean input__boolean--no-focus">
            <div 
                    @keydown.enter.prevent
                    @blur="addPlaceholder"
                    @keyup="saveCursorLocation($event); fixDelete(); clearHtmlElem($event);"
                    @input="updateBooleanInput($event); clearHtmlElem($event);"
                    @paste="pasted"
                    v-on:click="clearPlaceholder(); saveCursorLocation($event);"
                    class="input__boolean-content"
                    ref="divInput"
                    contenteditable="true">Cuvinte cheie, cautare booleana..</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
    .filters__toggler
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 2px;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

        .filters__toggler path
        {
            fill: #314964;
        }

    .filters__toggler-collapsed
    {
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }

    .input__label
    {
        font-family: $roboto;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #314964;
        letter-spacing: -0.13px;
        text-align: justify;
    }

    .input__boolean
    {
        width: 100%;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 1px solid #AFB0C3;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 7px 15px 7px;
        font-family: $opensans;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #082341;
        min-height: 40px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-top: 15px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        line-height: 22px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .input__boolean-content
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0px;
            word-break: break-word;
        }

        .input__boolean img
        {
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-bottom: -6px;
        }

    .input__boolean--no-focus
    {
        color: #9A9AA6
    }

.input__label-wrap
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

    .boolean-buttons
    {
        background-color: #007AFF;
        padding: 3px 15px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: $roboto;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 300;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

        .boolean-button--img
        {
            height: 22px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        .boolean-button--no-margin
        {
            margin: 0;
        }

.popper
{
    background-color: $darkbg;
    font-family: $opensans;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    border-color: $darkbg;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 12px 0 rgba(49,73,100,0.14);
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.filters__helper
{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.popper[x-placement^="top"] .popper__arrow
{
    border-color: #082341 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Note: ignore the new vue, it's pasted from the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Darkkz/r1u649pj/3/). I would suggest using the fiddle to inspect the code, reproduce the problem.

### Expected behaviour vs actual results

In Safari (latest version), if I type a word and then click somewhere in that word or move the caret in that word through the keyboard arrows then click one of the tags on the right side of the input, the tag should be added in the middle of clicked word (where was the selection made) but it is added at the beginning of the word.

tl;dr: Safari does not respect the caret's position when clicking one of the tags. It adds the tag at the beginning of the content editable div, not where the caret previously was.

**Edit 1**: Based on these logs, getSelection() teaches us that the offset is always 0 because in Safari, the div loses focus.
[image]

Comment: I'm still not sure what the problem is, but I sure can [simplify your test case](https://jsfiddle.net/652hzmxr/). Trim down the CSS a bit more (I didn't bother doing much to it) and it almost starts to look like a [mcve].

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thank you for the advice, indeed the rest of the buttons were redundant. I will get some time to update that fiddle. Regarding the problem, I made a gif with a comparison between Chrome (firefox acts as chrome) and Safari (the culprit). https://imgur.com/dpOmkFv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you basically found the answer yourself already. It is a timing issue.

If you change the event to mousedown, the caret position isn't lost and the tag gets inserted at the correct position.

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="input__label-wrap">
   <span class="input__label">Cauta</span>
   <div style="user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none">
    <span readonly v-on:mousedown="addBooleanTag(b_button)" v-for="b_button in boolean_buttons" class="boolean-buttons">{{b_button.label}}</span>
   </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="input__boolean input__boolean--no-focus">
   <div 
     @keydown.enter.prevent
     @blur="addPlaceholder"
     @keyup="saveCursorLocation($event); fixDelete(); clearHtmlElem($event);"
     @input="updateBooleanInput($event); clearHtmlElem($event);"
     @paste="pasted"
     v-on:click="clearPlaceholder(); saveCursorLocation($event);"
     class="input__boolean-content"
     ref="divInput"
     contenteditable="true">Cuvinte cheie, cautare booleana..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xmuzp20o/

If you don't want to add the actual tag on mousedown, then you could save the caret position at least in that event, so that you still have the correct position in the click event.

Comment: This solved my problem but..recently found out that opens other issues. On mousedown defocus the field while click adds the element and maintains the focus. If I change back to click, I have again the problems on Safari. If I switch to mousedown, I have the defocus on all browsers. If you want to see the behaviour, change mousedown to clock in your fiddle and run the fiddle then click one element. Any ideas? My first thought was... two methods, and a condition to check the user agent. Ran one on safari and one on the rest.

Comment: Sorry to hear that only solved your issue partially. My idea would be to try to readd the focus with the new caret position. That might open up another trove of issues though. So if applied, that should probably only be done in combination with checking the user agent (which is prone to errors already). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-keyboard-caret-position-in-html-textbox shows how the focus can be added with the caret position.... Hope that helps