# How to place the caret where it previously was after replacing the html of a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, caret

I have a contenteditable div where I replace hashtags with clickable links when the user clicks on space or on enter. The user writes down:

> I love but there is no fish at home|

He then realizes he made a mistake and then decides to go back and write

> I love #sushi | but there is no fish at home

```
#sushi
```

gets replaced by:

```
 <a href="https://google.com/sushi>#sushi</a>
```

Notice that the | shows the position of where I want the caret to be when the user presses spacebar. My current "placeCaretAtEnd" function places the caret at the end of the div and NOT behind the link that I just replaced *sushi* with. Is there a way to alter my current function to place the caret behind the link I just replaced in the text on the position shown above, so that the user can continue typing carelessly?  So in raw html:

> I love < a> #sushi< /a> | but there is no fish at home

```js
/**
* Trigger when someone releases a key on the field where you can post remarks, posts or reactions
*/
$(document).on("keyup", ".post-input-field", function (event) {

       // if the user has pressed the spacebar (32) or the enter key (13)
       if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
          let html = $(this).html();
          html = html.replace(/(^|\s)(#\w+)/g, " <a href=#>$2</a>").replace("<br>", ""); 
          $(this).html(html);
          placeCaretAtEnd($(this)[0]);
       }
  });

 /**
 * Place the caret at the end of the textfield
 * @param {object} el - the DOM element where the caret should be placed 
 */
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {

    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
        && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined"){
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class="post-input-field">
I love (replace this with #sushi and type space) but there is no fish at home
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rangy.js has a [text range module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) that lets you save selection as indices of the characters that are selected, and then restore it. Since your modifications do not alter `innerText`, this looks like a perfect fit:

```
      var sel = rangy.getSelection();
      var savedSel = sel.saveCharacterRanges(this);
      $(this).html(html);
      sel.restoreCharacterRanges(this, savedSel);
```

Implementing this manually requires careful traversal of the DOM inside `contenteditable` and careful arithmetics with the indices; this can't be done with a few lines of code.

Your `placeCaretAtEnd` can't possibly place the caret after the link you've inserted, since it doesn't "know" which (of the possibly multiple) link it is. You have to save this information beforehand.

```js
/**
* Trigger when someone releases a key on the field where you can post remarks, posts or reactions
*/
$(document).on("keyup", ".post-input-field", function (event) {

       // if the user has pressed the spacebar (32) or the enter key (13)
       if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
          let html = $(this).html();
          html = html.replace(/(^|\s)(#\w+)/g, " <a href=#>$2</a>").replace("<br>", ""); 
          var sel = rangy.getSelection();
          var savedSel = sel.saveCharacterRanges(this);
          $(this).html(html);
          sel.restoreCharacterRanges(this, savedSel);
       }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-textrange.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class="post-input-field">
I love (replace this with #sushi and type space) but there is no fish at home
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nick ,how can we do the same thing in sveltekit? can you please take a look, I've tried doing the same but its not that much jqury friendly..this is my code so far `function blueColor() {
  tweet = tweet.replace(/(^|\s)(#\w+)/g, " <a href=#>$2</a>").replace("<br>", ""); 

  var savedSel = sel.saveCharacterRanges(this);
          sel.restoreCharacterRanges(this, savedSel);
 }`

Comment: @equi your problem is unrelated and you'll have better chances if you ask a separate [easy-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question. Your code uses undefined `tweet` variable and is missing a call to actually update the innerHTML of the contenteditable (`$(elt).html(str)` in jQuery).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73649010/color-hashtags-while-typing-like-in-twitter-with-svelte here it is but I recently saw you answer

Comment: Posted there https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736340/1026 (only as a Svelte learning exercise; do not expect to get a production-ready solution to this on stackoverflow...)