# color #hashtags while typing like in twitter with svelte

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

I'm suing svelte and reactivity here is key, I want to color as I type #hashtags in my text,
code:

```
<script> 
let tweet = "";
        function blueColor() {
    tweet = tweet.replace(/<a\b[^>]*>|\B(#[^\W_][\w-]*)/gi, function (m, p) {
        return p ? '<span class="hash_tag">' + m + '</span>' : m;
    });
}
</script>
                               <input
                                    id="message"
                                    rows="4"
                                    bind:value={ tweet }
                                    on:input={ blueColor }
                                    class="block p-2.5 w-full 
                                    rounded-lg border text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring
                                    bg-gray-700 border-gray-600 placeholder-gray-400
                                    hover:border-blue-600"
                                    placeholder="What's happening..."
                                    maxlength="200"
                                />
```

as you can see I can replace it while I am typing but I get this as output:

```
as <span class="hash_tag">#hashtag</span>
```

Do you have any quick solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with @H.B.'s answer, I was asked if the [solution to *How to place the caret where it previously was after replacing the html of a contenteditable div?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546051/1026) could be used with svelte:

([open in Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8db1ee24c98041aca9f25cd342a25e79?version=3.50.1))

```
<svelte:head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-textrange.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    import { tick } from 'svelte';

    let div, html;
    let text = 'Type here';
    $: (async () => {
        if (!window.rangy) return;
        let sel = rangy.getSelection();
        let savedSel = sel.saveCharacterRanges(div);
        console.log(savedSel[0].characterRange, `"${text}"`, `"${html}"`)
        html = text.replace(/(^|\s)(#\w+)/g, " <a href=#>$2</a>");
        await tick();
        sel.restoreCharacterRanges(div, savedSel);
    })();
</script>

<div
    contenteditable
    bind:this={div}
    bind:innerHTML={html}
    bind:textContent={text}
></div>
```

This is not perfect (e.g. does not handle trailing spaces well in Firefox), only a translation of my other answer to svelte.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you have any quick solution

There is no quick solution to this. The only way to get styled text input is using [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) which tends to be highly complex in terms of interaction logic.

Your best bet is look for a library that already handles all of the necessities (handling copy/paste, removing unwanted input & formatting, etc.).

If you want to implement the logic yourself, `contenteditable="plaintext-only"` can be used to restrict input right away. Synchronizing state correctly, removing/adding the elements necessary for the tags without interfering with user input, might still be complicated, though.

Comment: Hi H, the problem is to color #hashtags while typing like in twitter with svelte not necessary a quick solution

Comment: You have to use `contenteditable` instead of an `input` and insert elements for the tags there. To my knowledge there is no other way.

Comment: I have actually but dont know why it displays the above...in fact it prints it out multiple times

Comment: You are adding HTML to text which is used as a value to an `input`, as I said *this will not work*.